# How to declare the return type of a function as a class (not instance) in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I need to declare that function returns a class definition (moreover generic). How can I do that?

Following works for non-generic classes, but does not work for generic:

```
export function composeAll(composeFunction: Function, depsFunction: Function):
(component: any) => typeof React.Component; // works

export function composeAll<V>(composeFunction: Function, depsFunction: Function):
(component: any) => typeof React.Component<V, {}>; // fails
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `typeof`. Just simply

```
export function composeAll(composeFunction: Function, depsFunction: Function): 
    (component: any) => React.Component;
```

And

```
export function composeAll<V>(composeFunction: Function, depsFunction: Function): 
    (component: any) => React.Component<V, {}>;
```

What you are trying to do is called a [type query](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#3.8.10), I don't think it's applicable here.